# how to Show and Hide Flash icon as per environments using AVCaptureSession?

Tags: iphone, swift, swift4, avcapturesession

I am using AVCaptureSession to take a photo and Record a Video. how can i show and Hide Flash icon as per environments(light or dark) in my Camera View

[image: here]